# Python JSON-RPC 2.0 API

Tags: python, api, json-rpc

I'm creating a **JSON-RPC API** on **Python** using ***json-rpc 1.10.3*** lib.

I've made the server and client.

On the server I've done two methods which connect to MySQl database and retrieve the dictionary I need and added them to the dispatcher.

But when I run the client, I'm getting the ***Response 405 (Method Not Allowed)***.

What's the problem?

**SERVER**

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from jsonrpc import JSONRPCResponseManager, dispatcher

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 80

def __init__(self, conn):
    self.conn = conn

@dispatcher.add_method
def get_detailed_usage(self, serviceRef, fromDate, toDate, excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance):
    sql_where = []
    sql_vars = []
    if serviceRef is not None:
        sql_where.append("pc.service_ref={}").format(serviceRef)
        sql_vars.append(serviceRef)
    if fromDate is not None:
        sql_where.append("rc.start_time={}").format(fromDate)
        sql_vars.append(fromDate)
    if toDate is not None:
        sql_where.append("rc.end_time={}").format(toDate)
        sql_vars.append(toDate)
    if excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance is not None:
        sql_where.append("excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance={}").format(excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance)
        sql_vars.append(excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance)
    sql_query = """
                SELECT...
                FROM...
                JOIN...
                ON...
                """
    if sql_where:
        sql_query += " WHERE" + " AND ".join(sql_where)
    cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_query, *sql_vars)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    return dict(result)


@dispatcher.add_method
def get_summary_usage(self, serviceRef, fromDate, toDate, excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance):
    sql_where = []
    sql_vars = []
    if serviceRef is not None:
        sql_where.append("pc.service_ref={}").format(serviceRef)
        sql_vars.append(serviceRef)
    if fromDate is not None:
        sql_where.append("rc.start_time={}").format(fromDate)
        sql_vars.append(fromDate)
    if toDate is not None:
        sql_where.append("rc.end_time={}").format(toDate)
        sql_vars.append(toDate)
    if excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance is not None:
        sql_where.append("excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance={}").format(excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance)
        sql_vars.append(excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance)
    sql_query = """
                SELECT...
                FROM...
                JOIN...
                ON...
                """
    if sql_where:
        sql_query += " WHERE" + " AND ".join(sql_where)
    cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_query, *sql_vars)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    return dict(result)

def application(request):
    response = JSONRPCResponseManager.handle(request.data, dispatcher)
    return Response(response.json, response.http_status, mimetype='application/json')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple(HOST, PORT, application)
```

**CLIENT**

```
import requests
import json


def main():
    url = 'http://localhost:80'
    # headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

    result = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "get_detailed_usage",
        "params": [{"serviceRef": "1234", "fromDate": "2017-01-01 00:00:00", "toDate": "2017-01-31 23:59:59"}],
        "id": 0,
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(result))

    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Try using `requests.get()` instead of `requests.post()`

Comment: @Leon Thanks. :)
But I thought that JSON-RPC 2.0 doesn't support GET request.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I have zero experience with json-rpc; and just thought that it might be a simple problem that you had overlooked. Is it your first attempt to decorate with `dispatcher.add_method` a free function that has a `self` parameter?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is in the `self` and `excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance` parameters of  `get_detailed_usage()`. I would debug this problem as follows: 1. temporarily replace your implementation of `get_detailed_usage()` with `def get_detailed_usage(**kwargs): print(kwargs)` and check that it works. 2. Then declare it as `def get_detailed_usage(serviceRef, fromDate, toDate)` (note the missing parameters `self` and `excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance`) and check that it works too. 3. Then add the `excludeCallsCoveredByBundleAllowance` parameter with a default value.

Answer (score 0):

I think in client side, the correct url should be

```
'http://localhost:80/jsonrpc'
```